# Git hook automatic installation

Tags: git, githooks

I am working in big project with many repositories with many branches and people who works with them. We have commit message standard but people are people and sometimes make this commit massages incorrect. That's why i create a git commit hook and now i need some how to install it on all users local repositories.

So the question is it possible to install this commit hook automatically not to ask users about it?

Comment: Is your commit message standard so complex that using a hook is a must? Why not let people do it manually?

Comment: Put the hook at `/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks`, or `/mingw64(or 32)/share/...` for windows, it can be copied into the git repo automatically when `git init` or `git clone` run.

Comment: @kajetons already tried do it manually but not all people do it and some of them continue tu commit not using commit msg standard :(

Comment: @ElpieKay ok ill try thx for advice

Answer (score 16):

> So the question is it possible to install this commit hook automatically not to ask users about it?

It's not.  Being able to automatically install scripts on a machine that will run without any intervention from the user is a substantial security issue, which is why there is no facility to do this.

There are a few things you can do:

- Provide a script in the repository that will configure your git hooks, and provide instructions to run the script after cloning the repository.
- Implement enforcement policies on your git server, so that if someone tries to push a change that doesn't meet your standards it will be rejected.  This will encourage people to install your local hooks.

Comment: we have automatic way in another prohect there we use ant + git which do install commit hook on local repo

Comment: That sounds very muck like the "provide a script" solution I mentioned.  Here, your ant tasks are your script.

Answer (score 4):

`export GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS="'core.hooksPath=.githooks'"`

This will run hooks stored in `.githooks` relative to your current repo.

Set this in your shell rc file and assuming you standardize on storing your hooks in a '.githooks' directory you won't have to set `git config` or link files in every repo.

#### Gotchas

The "danger" here is someone could put something malicious in a hook, but hey you checked before you cloned their repo right?